# Не работает RecycleView в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, списки

необходимо сделать прокрутку как в playstore, но к сожалению recycleview отображает некорректно заполняя только первый элемент списка всеми элементами. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1-й адаптер

```
public class CategoryRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<CategoryReference> categoryReferences;
    private ArrayList<ReferenceRecyclerAdapter> referenceRecyclerAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;


    public CategoryRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<CategoryReference> categoryReferences, Context context) {
        this.categoryReferences = categoryReferences;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_reference, parent, false);
        CategoryViewHolder categoryViewHolder = new CategoryViewHolder(view);
        return categoryViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final String categoryName = categoryReferences.get(position).getCategoryName();
        ArrayList<References> referencesList = categoryReferences.get(position).getReferencesList();
        holder.categoryName.setText(categoryName);
        ReferenceRecyclerAdapter referenceRecyclerAdapter = new ReferenceRecyclerAdapter(referencesList);
        holder.recycleItemReference.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.recycleItemReference.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        holder.recycleItemReference.setAdapter(referenceRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != categoryReferences ? categoryReferences.size() : 0);
    }

    public static class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView categoryName;
        RecyclerView recycleItemReference;

        public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);
            categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_name);
            recycleItemReference = itemView.findViewById(R.id.reference_pager);


        }
    }
```

2-й адаптер

```
public class ReferenceRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReferenceRecyclerAdapter.ReferenceViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<References> referencesList;

    public ReferenceRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<References> referencesList) {
        this.referencesList = referencesList;
    }

    @Override
    public ReferenceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_previous_references, parent, false);
        ReferenceViewHolder referenceViewHolder = new ReferenceViewHolder(view);
        return referenceViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ReferenceViewHolder holder, int position) {
        References itemRef = referencesList.get(position);
        holder.previousImage.setImageResource(itemRef.getImgPrevious());
        holder.previousText.setText(itemRef.getTxtPrevious());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != referencesList ? referencesList.size() : 0);
    }

    public static class ReferenceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView previousImage;
        TextView previousText;

        public ReferenceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            previousImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_previous);
            previousText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_previous);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите как заполняете список вложенного адаптера, а вообще попробуйте эту библиотеку - https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter она позволяет очень легко добавлять вложенные RecyclerView

Comment: Я выложил код вложенного адаптера.

Comment: я вижу, вопрос в другом - как формируется список для адаптера, судя по всему он как раз и не правильный. кстати - не нужно создавать каждый раз адаптер в методе `onBindView()` - его нужно создавать один раз для ячейки, после чего просто заменять там итемы

Comment: categoryReferenceList = new ArrayList<>();
        referencesList = new ArrayList<>();
        referencesList.add(new References("http://surviveclub.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Rwy0NUR85IM.jpg", "file:///android_asset/article.html"));
        referencesList.add(new References("https://cdn.fishki.net/upload/post/201506/11/1563302/steik-pork.jpg", "file:///android_asset/article.html"));
      
        categoryReferenceList.add(new CategoryReference("Категория 1","http://ck-magazine.ru/sites/default/files/field/image/happy_couple_2.jpg", referencesList));

Comment: судя по тому что вы скинули - вы заполняете только одну категорию и получаете соответсвующий результат